# How to generate a Shared Access Signature token for a Azure Storage container in NodeJS

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

Currently I have code in node JS that generates SAS tokens for blobs within a specified Azure Storage container. I want to be able to generate a SAS token that will grant the user access to the entire container itself, rather than generating tokens for each individual blob. How would I go about doing that? Below is the code that currently generates tokens for blobs.

```
const containerName = "samplecontainer";
const blobName = "sample.csv";

const account = "sampleaccount";
const key = process.env["StorageConKey"]; // storage connection key
const credentials = new storage.StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, key);

const blobSASToken = storage.generateBlobSASQueryParameters({ 
    containerName, 
    blobName, 
    permissions: storage.BlobSASPermissions.parse("r"), 
    startsOn: new Date(),
    expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 60000)
},
credentials).toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to generate a SAS token that will grant the user access to the entire container itself.

You can use the below node.js code to create a container SAS token and container URL with SAS-token.

**Code:**

```
const {BlobServiceClient,
    ContainerSASPermissions,
    generateBlobSASQueryParameters,
    SASProtocol,StorageSharedKeyCredential}  = require("@azure/storage-blob"); 
    
async  function  createContainerSas(){
    const  accountName = "venkat123";
    const  containerName = "test";
    const accountkey = "Your-account-key"
 
    const credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountkey);
  // Create a BlobServiceClient object using the StorageSharedKeyCredential object
  const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`, credential);
  // Get a reference to a container
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
 
  const  sasOptions = {
    containerName,
    protocol:  SASProtocol.HttpsAndHttp
    };
    sasOptions.permissions = ContainerSASPermissions.parse('c');
    sasOptions.expiresOn = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 3600*1000);
    const sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(sasOptions, credential).toString();
    
    console.log(`SAS token for blob container is: ${sasToken}`);
    console.log(`${containerClient.url}?${sasToken}`);
    }
 createContainerSas()
```

**Output:**

```
SAS token for blob container is: sv=2022-11-02&spr=https%2Chttp&se=2023-05-27T07%3A03%3A30Z&sr=c&sp=c&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test?sv=2022-11-02&spr=https%2Chttp&se=2023-05-27T07%3A03%3A30Z&sr=c&sp=c&sig=xxxxxxxx
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Create a service SAS for a container or blob with JavaScript - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/sas-service-create-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Is this a secure way to create Azure SAS Tokens? I don't want to include the account key in the code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `permissions: storage.ContainerSASPermissions.parse("r")` ?

Here the relative documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/containersaspermissions?view=azure-node-latest

Comment: Yes, I tried replacing the original permissions with permissions: storage.ContainerSASPermissions.parse("r"). I also tried removing the blobName to no avail.

Comment: Does your application have the necessary permissions to provide access at the storage account level?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a beginner with Node JS and Azure's services, how do I check the permissions? I assumed that this wouldn't be an issue as my code was creating SAS tokens at the blob level.

Comment: @bowlingh23 - what are the issues you are running into?

Comment: Take a look at the "storage connection key". This key contains the permissions to create SAS at a certain level (service, container, blob). I think that in your case, the permissions are set on the container content and not on the container service.

To remedy this, you can do as @Venkatesan suggested (taking care to adapt the generated SAS permission to 'r' as in your code snippet). In addition, I recommend using a SAS token instead of an account key (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview).